# In App Purchased not working in Live

Tags: objective-c, app-store, in-app-purchase, xcode5

Last night my app approved for sale in the app store, my surprise was that by downloading, the In Purchased app not working, as if they were live.
I read that Apple's taking 24 to 48 hours when live IAP.
Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

> I read that Apple's taking 24 to 48 hours when live IAP. Is that true?

Yes it is.

Each In app purchase is going over a review like a new app.